# Tunnel serial com port windows 10

Tags: python, windows, serial-port, visa, pyvisa

I'm currently developing a python automation which communicates and control FPGA platform via serial com port. The platform connected to a PC setup in the lab at my workplace. to connect to the FPGA with Python i'm using pyvisa as follows:

```
    import pyvisa as visa
    rm = visa.ResourceManager('@py')
    self.inst = rm.open_resource('ASRL8::INSTR')
```

my problem:
To test my code I must pull the new code to the lab-PC.
Is there a way that i'll "tunnel" the serial com port so I can can connect to the FPGA from my PC over LAN ? or any other method that will enable me to connect to the FPGA platform using my development PC ?

*an additional hardware can be considered if needed...

```
'ASRL8::INSTR' --> 'TCPIP0::LABPC-IP::inst0::INSTR'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is called Virtual Com Port, VCP, and can run both TCP and UDP.

Search for "Virtual Com Port TCP" for instance and you get a lot of software you can install to manage that.

Comment: any known recommendations ? open-sourced / paid ?

Comment: @Udi_W, It was a couple of years ago I used VCPs so there are probably better today. Now I use Ethernet directly instead in most projects. I think that is easier.